# Hide AJAX message after PDF is created

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am submitting a form using php and ajax. The form sends HTML output to a different page that creates a pdf.  The submit is working fine, but I can't seem to hide to the waiting message after the pdf is created.  I have tried a few different ways without success.

Here is the form code:

```
<div id="message" style="display: none;"></div>
<div id="waiting" style="display: none;">Please wait</div>

<form action="/export-to-pdf" method="POST" id="pdfform" >
    <input type="hidden" name="var1" value="<?=$var1;?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="var2" value="<?=$var2;?>">
    <input type="submit" id="pdfsubmit" name="pdfsubmit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Here is the important code from the page that creates the pdf:

```
$pdf->Output('form.pdf', 'D');
    $return = array();
    $return['success'] = "success";
    echo json_encode($return);
```

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#pdfsubmit').click(function() {

    $('#waiting').show(500);
    $('#pdfform').hide(0);
    $('#message').hide(0);

    $.ajax({
        type : 'POST',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        url : '/export-to-pdf',
        data: serialize(),
        success : function(response){
        if (response.success == 'success') {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass((data.error === true) ? 'error' : 'success')
                .text(data.msg).show(500);
            if (data.error === true)
                $('#pdfform').show(500);
            }
        }
        ,
        error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $('#waiting').hide(500);
            $('#message').removeClass().addClass('error')
                .text('There was an error.').show(500);
            $('#pdfform').show(500);
        }
    });

    return false;
});
```

});

A "Save As" dialog box is shown once the pdf is ready for download, but the ajax message still appears on the screen and never goes away.  I am using TCPDF class to build the pdf file.

Comment: The <DIV> naming was not the cause.  I am still struggling with this.  Even firebug shows a 200 Status after posting, but the waiting message is still shown.  It is working on the same site when I post to the same page.  The waiting message is displayed, the data is refreshed and then the waiting message is hidden.  I am wondering if there is something wierd with handling the PDF creation that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your please wait is in the load div... not that waiting div...
$('#load').hide(0);

Comment: Sorry about that, I was not using the latest update.  I editing the OP.  It is not working with that code.

Answer (score 0):

Your waiting message is inside the div with id **load** and not **waiting**. You should change the following

```
<div id="load" style="display:none;">Please wait.</div>
```

to

```
<div id="waiting" style="display:none;">Please wait.</div>
```

Comment: I had an extra <DIV> inside the "waiting" <DIV> which has since been removed.  THe issue has not been resolved.  The waiting message is shown, but never goes away, even after the PDF "Save As" dialog is shown.